# Update a column everytime a new row is added to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like this:

```
    use_id  user_id platform    platform_version    device
0   22782   26980   ios         10.2                iPhone7
1   22783   29628   android     6.0                 Nexus 5
2   22784   28473   android     5.1                 SM-G903F
3   22785   15200   ios         10.2                iPhone7
4   22786   28239   android     6.0                 ONE E1003
5   22787   12921   android     4.3                 GT-I9505
6   22788   28714   android     6.0                 SM-G930F
7   22789   28714   android     6.0                 SM-G930F
8   22790   29592   android     5.1                 D2303
9   22791   28775   ios         10.2                iPhone6
```

and a second dataframe df2 (subset of df1):

```
    use_id  user_id   device       date_created
0   22782   26980     iPhone7      2018/12/12
1   22783   29628     Nexus 5      2019/01/15
2   22784   28473     SM-G903F     2019/01/23
3   22785   15200     iPhone7      2019/01/23
4   22786   28239     ONE E1003    2019/01/23
```

I want to identify the new rows in df1 not present in df2, append them to df2 and then update the 'date_created' column with the entry date.

So df2 will be similar to this:

```
    use_id  user_id   device       date_created
0   22782   26980     iPhone7      2018/12/12
1   22783   29628     Nexus 5      2019/01/15
2   22784   28473     SM-G903F     2019/01/23
3   22785   15200     iPhone7      2019/01/23
4   22786   28239     ONE E1003    2019/01/23   
5   22787   12921     GT-I9505     2019/05/22
6   22788   28714     SM-G930F     2019/05/22
7   22789   28714     SM-G930F     2019/05/22
8   22790   29592     D2303        2019/05/22
9   22791   28775     iPhone6      2019/05/22
```

I was able to get the difference of both dataframes using merge():

```
mergedStuff = pd.merge(df1['use_id', 'user_id', 'device'], df2, on=['use_id', 'user_id', 'device'], how='outer', indicator=True).loc[mergedStuff['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

and then append the new rows to df2:

```
df2 = df2.append(mergedStuff, ignore_index=True)
```

But I am struggling how to add the created date like below only for new appended rows.

`df2['date_created'] = pd.datetime.now()`

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join to merge the two frames and set indicator to True:

```
df_merged=pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',indicator=True)
```

Filter out the rows contained in the left frame only

```
df_merged=df_merged.loc[df_merged['_merge']=='left_only']
```

df_merged['Created']=pd.Timestamp.now()

Comment: directly do like: `pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',indicator=True).query('_merge=="left_only"')` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas built in datetime functionality to add the date created field to df1 prior to merging.

```
df1['date_created'] = pd.Timestamp.now()
#to keep just the date part
df1['date_created'] = df1['date_created'].dt.date
```